# retrieve the selected value from database for checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following lines of code:

newlink.aspx:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSend" runat="server" Text="Sent Details to User" />
```

newlink.aspx.cs:

```
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sent_details", chkSend.Checked ? "1" : "0");
```

editlink.aspx:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSend" runat="server" Text="Sent Details to User" Checked='<%# Bind("sent_details") %>'/></td>
```

editlink.aspx.cs:

```
 command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sent_details", chkSend.Checked);
```

I am not getting the checkbox field ticked in edit form if am ticking it in Insert form.I have used Checked in editlink.aspx in order to get the selected value from the database but it is not working fine.So what should i do inorder to get the selected value ie.ticked checkbox?

Comment: in the code behind for "editlink.aspx" you need to extract the value for sent_details.

Comment: thanks dani....i have resolved the issue...i have used datatable to fetch it from the database..and its working fine now...